# Return the id of a created record

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that creates a movie,

```
createMovie.create({
  release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
  imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
  title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
  image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
  movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id,
  backdrop:       $scope.movieListID.backdrop_path
}).
```

This calls the createMovie service,

```
app.factory('createMovie', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    create: function(movie){
      return $http.post('/movies.json', movie);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Is it possible to return the id of this created record?

Comment: Yes, handle it in when resolving the `$http` promise.  Obviously, you'll need the server to return the id of the successfully created movie in the server response.

Comment: Can do this: `createMovie.create(...).then(function(response) { var id = response.id });`

Comment: Wouldn't it be `response.data.id`?

Comment: depends what is contained within the response from the server!

Comment: I guess you are right, but a lot of newbies tries to access the wrong response when they change from `.success` callback to promise `.then` so I just wanted to clarify that

Comment: @Ric The response returns an object, but there's no id in it.

Comment: so what properties of the object are there that you can use for the `id`? i just took a guess that it was called `id` - only you know what it will be

Comment: @ryanyuyu How would I return that id?

Comment: @Ric none. I'm trying to return the id of the record in my own database. For example if I have 6 records, and add another then I want to return `7` (since it's the seventh record in the table).

Comment: @PeterBoomsma that's server-side code.  So your question really isn't angular.  It's about server code (asp-mvc?, php?) to return data in a successful http response.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the correct flow should be

1. Post a data to backend to save it
2. Backend validates and saves

   2a. Success save

   1. return 200 with the saved element JSON
   2. handle success

   2b. Failed save

   1. Return error 400
   2. Handle the error

---

```
createMovie.then(successCallback, errorCallback)

function successCallback (response) {
  $scope.movies.push(response.data) //example - add saved movie to list of movies
}

function errorCallback (response) {
  alert(response.data.errorMessage)
  //something went terribly wrong, let the user know
}
```

That way when you return http error code you don't have to handle the error in success call.

> Note that `response` in this example contains response headers and the actuall response that server returned would be in `response.data`